# Не работает сохранение файлов на сервере: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mv')

Tags: node.js, path, node-modules

Почему сервер не может прочитать mv?
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mv')

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
import * as path from 'path';

class fileService{
saveFile(file){
    try{
        const fileName = uuid.v4()+'.png';
        const filePath = path.resolve('static',fileName);
        file.mv(filePath);
        return fileName;
    }

    catch (e){
        console.log(e)}       

}
}
export default new fileService();
```

Postman пишет "goodsData validation failed: image: Path `image` is required."

goodsData:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const goodsData = new mongoose.Schema({

    "name":{type:String,required:true},
    "desc":{type:String,required:true},
    "price":{type:Number,required:true},
    "image":{type:String,required:true},
    "full_desc":{type:String,required:true},
    "type_id":{type:String,required:true},
    "stones":{type:String,required:true},
    "metal_id":{type:String,required:true},      
   })

    export default mongoose.model('goodsData', goodsData)
```

Роутер:

```
import goodsDataController from "./goodsDataController.js";

const router = new Router()

router.post('/goods_page', goodsDataController.create)
```

Controller:

```
import goodService from "./goodService.js"

class goodsDataController{
async create(req,res){
    try{
        
        const createdGood = await goodService.create(req.body)
        res.json(createdGood)
    
    
        } catch(e){
            res.status(500).json(e.message)
    
        }

}
```

Service:

```
import fileService from "./fileService.js";
import goodsData from "./goodsData.js";

class goodService{
async create(createdGood,image){
    const fileName=fileService.saveFile(image)
    

    const createdGoodData = await 
    goodsData.create({...createdGood,image:fileName});
    return createdGoodData;          
}
```

Comment: Так а что такое `file`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen картинка из тела запроса

Comment: И где же вызывается метод `saveFile`? Судя по ошибке туда ничего не передаётся.

Comment: @AlexeyTen обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну и вы тут передали один аргумент `goodService.create(req.body)`, а тут ожидаете `image` вторым аргументом `async create(createdGood,image)`. Конечно будет undefined. Впрочем даже если не `undefined`, то откуда у него должен взяться метод `mv` я не понимаю

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да,ошибка оказалась в этом,я думал,что node сам вытащит файл,а оказалось ,нужно было указать вторым аргументом req.files.image,спасибо вам!